# SVG dynamic rendering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, svg, anonymous-function, protovis

I'm trying to add and create SVG elements using JavaScript libraries and I've come across a common theme that I'd like to troubleshoot.

For example, I'm making an AJAX request and generating a dot on a map based on the returned values of latitude and longitude (using Polymaps, though this has happened with Protovis as well). When I run it once, it works fine. As an example, this is what gets returned from the server

```
[{'lat':29.6196787,'lng':-95.6349463},{'lat':42.3584308,'lng':-71.0597732}]
```

I then assign this to a variable and let the library handle the rendering.

When I incorporate an interactive feature where I make more requests and add more dots, nothing shows up in Chrome unless I resize the window or click around the page (it's like the dots are there but it has to refresh?) In Firefox everything seems to work fine.

I'm thinking this may have to do with global vs. local variable scoping but I can't seem to understand why. Someone once mentioned using anonymous self-invoking functions, but I'm generally confused. Can I get some help?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide a pared-down example of your problem online anywhere, so that we may reproduce your results?

Comment: SVG is scalable, Chrome and firefox render less than pixel size elements differently and sometimes the scale causes dots not to show up or in the case of maps borders not to show up. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3998254/svg-image-zoom-and-borders/4012063#4012063 Your code is not shown, so I need to ask what you may consider a dump question; If you place a very big rect with your code does it show up?

Comment: Yes it does. Everything renders correctly initially. It's when I try to repeat the procedure that I see it doesn't get performed correctly in Chrome, but it works in Firefox.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have the same problem where I dynamically change a SVG path based on AJAX data.  The lines on a chart, made up of multiple dynamic paths does not display in Chrome after it loads data unless I zoom in or out in the browser, which somehow causes the Chrome to rerender the SVG content. The SVG works perfectly in both Firefox and IE (using the Abode plugin). 

I'm currently digging for some sort of method to force Chrome to redraw the SVG whenever new data arrives.

Comment: I found the cause of the re-rendering problem I was having.  There is a bug in Chrome SVG support that makes dynamically rendered objects covered by a filter to not change.  Here's a link to the bug submission.    http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68971

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, maybe it's gonna help, there's a reload function on the layer object.

http://polymaps.org/docs/layer.html#reload

Comment: This reloads the tiles but not necessarily the dots. I think this issue isn't necessarily related to the fact that I'm using Polymaps. Thank you though!